# Woocommerce custom shipping by country and number of products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good afternoon prompt as possible to implement delivery to woocommerce. Mb i can use shipping plugin or custom funcntion.

**For Germany only**

- 1-3 product in cart- total shipping = 2.20€
- 4-5 products in cart- total shipping = 4.50€
- 6 or more products in cart - total shipping = free

**For other europe countries**

- 1-3 product in cart- total shipping = 3.80€
- 4-5 products in cart - total shipping = 7.99€
- 6 or  more products in cart- total shipping = free

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: you can write WooCommerce plugin yourself. (p.s. I have seen something similar before, go search for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty all. Im find this plugin [WooCommerce Shipping By Rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shipping-by-rules-for-woocommerce/)